# jQuery method for plain function execute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nice jQuery chain like this:

```
$(...)
    .method1()
    .method2()
    .method3()
    ...;
```

Now I see I would like to replace `.method2()` with a condition to run either `.method2a()` or `.method2b(p1)`. In fact, I want to do this:

```
$(...)
    .method1();

if (cond)
    $(...).method2a()
else
    $(...).method2b(p1)

$(...)
    .method3()
    ...;
```

but this is ugly - it breaks the beautiful chain!

So I am looking for jQuery API method XYZ that would allow me to run my own function in the chain! So it would look like this:

```
$(...)
    .method1()
    .XYZ(function () {
        if (cond)
            this.method2a()
        else
            this.method2b(p1);
    })
    .method3()
    ...;
```

So, is there any jQuery method XYZ that would allow this? The closest to this is `.each`, but I don't like to run it separately for each element!

Answer (score 5):

I really hate what i'm going to tell you and I think it is ugly, but you can use this:

```
$(...)
.method1()
[cond ? 'method2a' : 'method2b']()
.method3();
```

**Second solution:**

Add this code to your files

```
(function($){
    if(!$.fn.if)
        $.fn.if = function(cond, trueFn, falseFn){
            if(cond)
                trueFn.call(this);
            else
                falseFn.call(this);

            return this
        }
})(jQuery)
```

Editted: formatting

This will give you acces to the function `.if()` which can be used like that :

```
$('body').if(cond, 
         function(){
             this.addClass('a')
         },
         function(){
             this.addClass('b')
         })
```

Comment: Wow, a ternary inside an indexing operator.  I never thought of that.  That is cringe-worthy but quite clever :)

Comment: This is perfect!! I totally forgot that `.xy` is only a shortcut for parametrizable `['xy']`! Love this!! PS: don't understand why you guys hate it, this is clean and correct solution :)

Comment: Ouch! This will not work in my case! Because `method2a` and `method2b` take different parameters! What a pity!

Comment: @Tomas well you can still use ternary operator as parameter, but it is even more ugly : `[cond ? 'method2a' : 'method2b'](cond ? valu1 : value 2)`.

Comment: well, but the first method takes no parameters. Or maybe just passing null to it would do the job?

Comment: undefined, null both can do the job.

Comment: Thanks! But... this already is super-ugly - I will probably prefer to break the chain and keep my code readable :-)

Comment: @Tomas added an alternative. You can check it out. Anyway, good luck with that! :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a built-in for this, but this is a very simple plugin:

```
(function() {

    $.fn.XYZ = function(fn) {
        fn.call(this);
        return this;
    }; 

} ());
```

Comment: +1 thanks but I hate to create plugin for this :-) In that case I will go for the primitive solution sketched in the question..